# how to get data from number of functions written in same file for different mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, function-call

Angularjs code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl",$scope,$http){
$scope.displayData = function(){
$http.get( "Fetch_Data.php"
  ).then(function (response) {
   $scope.names = response.data; 
   },function (error){ 
   });
  }  
 }
```

Fetch_Data.php file:

```
<?php
// code for connection to database
function fun_1()
{
  //  mysql select query;
    return $output;
}
function fun_2()
{
    //  mysql select query;
   return $output;
}
$var_1 = fun_1();
$var_2 = fun_2();
?>
```

My question is **how to get data from number of functions written in same file for different mysql queries?**
How can i come to know that coming data in $http.get(), is from fun_1() or fun_2()?

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP needs to return (echo) a JSON data. Also you have to invoke the defined `displayData()` JS function. Here you are a complete example based on your code:

**JS/HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            let app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.displayData = function () {
                    $http.get("fetch_data.php"
                    ).then(function (response) {
                        $scope.names = response.data;
                    }, function (error) {
                    });
                };
                $scope.displayData();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-repeat="name in names">
                {{ name }}
            </div>
            <br>or to access by property:<br><br>
            <div ng-repeat="name in names">
                {{ name.function }}: {{ name.data }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP (fetch_data.php):**

```
<?php
    // code for connection to database
    function fun_1() {
        //  mysql select query;
        $output = 'MySQL Data 1';
        return array('function' => __FUNCTION__, 'data' => $output);
    }

    function fun_2() {
        //  mysql select query;
        $output = 'MySQL Data 2';
        return array('function' => __FUNCTION__, 'data' => $output);
    }

    $var_1 = fun_1();
    $var_2 = fun_2();
    $result = array($var_1, $var_2);

    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
{"function":"fun_1","data":"MySQL Data 1"}
{"function":"fun_2","data":"MySQL Data 2"}

or to access by property:

fun_1: MySQL Data 1
fun_2: MySQL Data 2
```

Further you can do whatever you want with returned JSON data. And of course you have to fulfil both PHP `$output` variables with your real DB data. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, right now i am checking this one.

Comment: I have updated slightly PHP code in order to have more proper JSON output and the HTML accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you must echo your output and use json format .

```
<?php
// code for connection to database
function fun_1()
{
  //  mysql select query;
    return $output;
}
function fun_2()
{
    //  mysql select query;
   return $output;
}
$var_1 = fun_1();
$var_2 = fun_2();

$result = array(
'name'=>'reza'

);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Why would the OP want to see your name returned to his script. It would be better to show them how to return the 2 values they were interested in

Comment: Also what would the OP do with this JSONString when it gets back to their script

Answer (score 0):

Add field to returned data.

```php
<?php
// code for connection to database
function fun_1()
{
  //  mysql select query;

    return [
        'result' => $output,
        'source' => 'fun_1'
    ];
}
function fun_2()
{
    //  mysql select query;
   return [
        'result' => $output,
        'source' => 'fun_2'
   ];
}
$var_1 = fun_1();
$var_2 = fun_2();
?>
```

But you have to modify how to read returned data

```
$scope.names = response.data.result;
console.log(response.data.source);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants ONE response containing 2 answers